# how to fix 'batch_size' in LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

I am running a LSTM code, and I want to make it Bidirectional LSTM. How do I go about this?

I am using the code from https://github.com/brunnergino/JamBot.git. The notebook named **polyphonic_lstm_training.py** has the code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_size, batch_size=batch_size, input_shape=(step_size, new_num_notes+chord_dim+counter_size), stateful=True))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_size, batch_input_shape=(batch_size,step_size, new_num_notes+chord_dim+counter_size), stateful=True))
```

I expect it to train using Bidirectional LSTM

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to implementing bidirectional LSTM is to reverse the input prior to processing it by a second LSTM layer. Then reverse the output of the second LSTM again and concatenate with with the output of the first LSTM layer.